# How to run command on desktop unlock

Tags: system, touchpad, lenovo

I have problems with a touchpad on Lenovo X1 Gen 5th.
Each time I unlock my screen session the touchpad is not functioning 100%, namely finger gestures for scrolling are messed up.

I have to run the following command in order to fix it:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse
```

My question is: how can I automate that command to be executed each time I unlock the screen?

I have tried scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` but with no luck.

Comment: Why don't you try first blacklisting that module? Sometimes your touchpad works fine afterwards. You do it adding `blacklist psmouse` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: Why would I do it? I guess I need it for my touchpad to work, do I ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your problem is that your touchpad doesn't work after suspend right? According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Touchpad_does_not_work_after_resuming_from_hibernate/suspend) it's a possible solution for the cases that your touchpad can work with another module.

Comment: nah, my touchpad is working but not 100%, scrolling has lags for example. Once I reload psmouse module all is working fine. but how can I automate it to be executed every time I unlock my screen?

Comment: [Check this guide](https://blog.christophersmart.com/2016/05/11/running-scripts-before-and-after-suspend-with-systemd/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. However there is no  /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep in Juno.

Comment: Here is my workaround:
Created a custom shortcut WIN+R and assigned it to the following script:

#!/bin/bash

sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse && notify-send -i emblem-nowrite "Touchpad" "Reloaded"

Now pressing Win+R does reload nice and quickly.
ehh...

Comment: The first comment of that website says that the path for debian/ubuntu based distros (like elementary) is `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`

Comment: Indeed, it is a detail which is easy to miss. I implemented this solution. That would ensure that after sleep and resume psmodule will get reloaded. This should do.

Comment: I also have this issue on Juno. While I tied to go through the link shared above for the answer, but I am not a programmer, so not sure how to create the script and what to write there. Please can you help in sharing how to create the script and what script to write to automate it. The solution given in the question of running the command "sudo rmmod psmouse" and "sudo modprobe psmouse" works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we have to answer our questions ourselves to close it:)

> If you want to do something before you suspend, like unload a module
>   or run some script, it’s quite easy with systemd. Similarly, you can
>   easily do something when the system resumes (like reload the module).
>
> The details are in the systemd-suspend man page: man
>   systemd-suspend.service
>
> Simply put an executable script of any name under
>   /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/ that checks whether the first argument
>   is pre (for before the system suspends) or post (after the system
>   wakes from suspend).
>
> If it is pre, then do the thing you want to before suspend, if it’s
>   post then do the thing you want to do after resume. Simple!
>
> Here’s a useless example:
>   `#!/bin/sh if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then   # Do the thing you want before suspend here, e.g.:   echo "we are suspending at $(date)..." >
>   /tmp/systemd_suspend_test elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then   # Do the
>   thing you want after resume here, e.g.:   echo "...and we are back
>   from $(date)" >> /tmp/systemd_suspend_test fi`

So, I implemented this solution from here
https://blog.christophersmart.com/2016/05/11/running-scripts-before-and-after-suspend-with-systemd/
That would ensure that after sleep and resume psmodule will get reloaded. This should do.

Comment: Tried this as well but with no luck. I fixed all my problems with touchpad and killing gala process each time I disconnected remote Monitor by Installing Linux Mint MATE. Thanks! And have fun with eOS.